# How do I change the date format in iOS?

Tags: ios, text, internationalization, formatting

I live in the U.S., so my region is in the U.S. I want to make the iPad use the following formats:

- Fahrenheit for temperature
- Kilometers for distance
- USD for currency
- **`YYYY-MM-DD` date format**
- `HH:mm` 24-hour time format.

**How do I set up iOS to respect these preferences of mine?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time and date format can be set according to the generally accepted usage in a particular region in iOS devices.

Regions are selected in `Settings>General>International>Region Format`.

---

Sorry I misunderstood the question, I'm adding in the following more details.

Independently from the region you can always set the **24-hour time format** in: `Settings>General>Date & Time>24-Hour Time`, the **temperature scale** in `Weather` options and the **distance scale** in: `Settings>Maps`.

Anyway, as far as I know, you can't set **date format** and/or **currency**, in a different way from the specified region.

Comment: So... what region gives my the formats I specify in my question?

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for the update! I voted it up, but I can't bring myself to accept an answer of "as far as I know, what you want isn't possible." I hope that's OK.

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero yes sure, I totally agree. You can wait a few days and then also _start a bounty_ . I'm also curious to know how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Set the region to Canada to get metric date format.

Comment: Or Australia, or anywhere in the UK, or basically anywhere that's not America... ;)

Comment: Actually, UK gives a weird date format too. So do a bunch of EU countries. Canada works and results in ISO date format.